# User login action is not working, showing invalid username and password in CakePHP3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am trying to implement login functionality in CakePHP3 by following all prescribed ways. I have already tried many alternatives apart from main method found on Authentication page of official Cake website.

The error, I am receiving is "Invalid username or password". Below is a snapshot of code, I have used. Please note, I have followed proper naming conventions of CakePHP so no config issue should be there. Plus the issue is in 3.x version so don't answer for older versions please.

File: UsersController > Login Action

```
public function login() {
    if($this->Auth->user()){
        $this->Flash->error(__('You are already logged in!'));
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            $this->Flash->success(__('You\'re successfully logged-in.'));
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
    }
}
```

File: AppController > Initialize Function

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login',
        ],
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'username']
            ]
        ],
        'storage' => 'Session'
    ]);
    $this->Auth->allow(['display']);
    $this->Auth->allow(['register']);
}
```

File: Login View

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create();
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->button('Login', ['class' => 'btn']);
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Hope, I haven't missed anything but still it is not working as intended.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working without PasswordHasher in Auth component.
You should add it in /src/Model/Entity/User.php

Add below code at the end. Also add use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;

```
protected function _setPassword($value){
        $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
        return $hasher->hash($value);
    }
```

After this add new user and try to login with it.

Comment: Yeah. That is working fine but now I am unable to check the login status using the below code:

        if($this->Auth->user()){
            $this->Flash->error(__('You are already logged in!'));
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }

Comment: Dude, ignore my previous comment. Actually, I was trying to use this (login status check) code in AppController while I should use it in UsersController.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any error you are getting?Debugging mode must be on.

Comment: No error so far. Will comment if the code gets stuck anywhere. n Thanks buddy! :)

Comment: @6924563 @vipul-patel  : I am using **JWT auth** in **CakePHP 3.7** for authentication on my **Android App**. And, the line `$this->Auth->identify()` always returns `false`. Would you suggest why it's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Is your user entity using the DefaultPasswordHasher in the file src/Model/Entity/User.php?
Just a thought...

Comment: No. But I guess it is not required until and unless I am not encrypting password using PasswordHasher. Still I would appreciate to try this as well. Plz suggest what code do you think, I should use.